# C++ Regular Expressions

Tags: c++, regex, poco-libraries

I'm new to regular expressions - I am using Poco in C++ to pull IP addresses from a string and (trying) to put all IP matches into a string vector:

```
string result = tcpClient.receiveRaw();

RegularExpression re("\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b");

RegularExpression::MatchVec matches;
re.match(result, 0, matches);

IPlist = result.substr(matches[1].offset, matches[1].length);
```

I don't think the last line is correct (not sure how it works) I'm trying to pull all IP addresses from that initial string and add them to a string vector.

Comment: I don't know about Poco. But I would suggest to look at regular expressions of boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @ChristianSeverin Please be aware that every edit you make pushes the question to the front page and can create a lot of noise . If you believe the retagging should happen, ask about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) first.

Answer (score 2):

The expression can be shortened and the `\b` probably needs another escape (but I am not familiar with Poco so I could be way off). Try this out:

```
RegularExpression re("\\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the C POSIX regular expressions in ? Here's the documentation:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/regcomp.html

Beyond that, what's actually wrong here? You didn't specify an actual problem. I'm not familiar with the class you're using but nothing looks obviously broken, except that we don't know what IPlist is. It appears to be a list but is being set to equal a single string value. I suspect the logic there may be undesirable.